# Pattern Matching using Grep and/or RegEx to Extract ID from metadata field in R

Tags: r, regex

I have metadata strings that look like this:

```
{\"vote\":\"com.jivesoftware.community.acclaim.impl.VoteImpl@8b6b31f7\",\"referringSource\":null,\"referringUser\":null,\"acclaim\":\"AcclaimImpl{acclaimID=3146, object=EntityDescriptor{objectID=1900, objectType=102}, acclaimType='like', visibility=true, creationDate=Mon Jul 13 11:52:18 PDT 2014, modificationDate=Mon Jul 13 11:52:18 PDT 2014, properties={}}\",\"create\":true}
```

and I need to extract the `objectID`. I've been trying to use pattern matching, but I keep getting either

1. No matches
2. The entire metadata returned to me, or
3. Unexpected results

For example, I create this object for a simple test:

```
testme <- "{\"vote\":\"com.jivesoftware.community.acclaim.impl.VoteImpl@8b6b31f7\",\"referringSource\":null,\"referringUser\":null,\"acclaim\":\"AcclaimImpl{acclaimID=3246, object=EntityDescriptor{objectID=1400, objectType=102}, acclaimType='like', visibility=true, creationDate=Mon Jul 14 11:52:18 PDT 2014, modificationDate=Mon Jul 14 11:52:18 PDT 2014, properties={}}\",\"create\":true}"
```

and I try the following, which seems to work fine when I create and test it in a program called `RegEx Magic`, with my version of R specified in that program:

```
grep("\\AobjectID=[0-9]+[[:>:]]\\z", testme, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE);
```

yet the result I get is:

```
character(0)
```

I've tried some simpler approaches, such as:

```
regexpr(pattern="\\<objectID=[0-9]{1,4}", testme, useBytes = FALSE, fixed = TRUE)
```

and

```
regexpr(pattern="\\bobjectID=[0-9]", testme, useBytes = FALSE)
```

and those lead to the unexpected results (i.e. I'm not sure what it's giving me, but it's not what I'm looking for):

```
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

or

```
[1] 176
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 10
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

, respectively. If I remove the `\\b` or `\\<` then it returns the entire metadata string.

Could someone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `\A` is an anchor for the start of the string and `\z` for the end of the string, It's normal you didn't obtain a result, since what you are looking for is in the middle of the string. When you use `perl = TRUE` you can forget this kind of old POSIX/SQL boundaries: `[[:>:]]`, use `\b` instead.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, what's the weird result I got with `\b`?

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary that matches either the position between a member of the `\w` class and a non-member character or between a non-member and a member of the character class `\w`. For your case, you only need to use it at the begining (because you are looking for a letter (O) not preceded by an other letter) and since the number (member) is followed by a comma (a non-member). In R language, you must write `\\bObjectID=\\d+` (no need to put a boundary at the end, since the quantifier `+` is greedy (in other words you will obtain all possible digits)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using your first sample string.  It matches the regular expression and returns the portion within parentheses:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(s, "objectID=(\\d+)")[[1]]
[1] "1900"
```

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, the reason you get a result of `character(0)` is because your regular expression is incorrect. The `\A`   anchor matches the  position at start of the string, `\z` anchor matches the position at the very end of the string.

The substring you are searching for is at **neither position** in the string, in fact it's in the middle. So you need to remove the anchors and you can remove the character class related boundary and `perl=T` as well.

```
> grep("objectID=[0-9]+", x, value=TRUE)
# [1] "{\"vote\":\"com.jivesoftware.community.acclaim.impl.VoteImpl@8b6b31f7\",\"referringSource\":null,\"referringUser\":null,\"acclaim\":\"AcclaimImpl{acclaimID=3246, object=EntityDescriptor{objectID=1900, objectType=102}, acclaimType='like', visibility=true, creationDate=Mon Jul 14 11:52:18 PDT 2014, modificationDate=Mon Jul 14 11:52:18 PDT 2014, properties={}}\",\"create\":true}"
```

**Note:** `grep(value = TRUE)` returns a character vector containing the selected elements.

If you want to grab the substring value, base R handles this just fine.

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('(?<=\\bobjectID=)\\d+', x, perl=T))[[1]]
# [1] "1900"
```

Or you can simply use the `stringr` library to do this.

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(x, perl('(?<=\\bobjectID=)\\d+'))
# [1] "1900"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and you're clearly correct. I have to ask tho -- why does it work in my RegEx app (I used RegEx Magic/Buddy and someone trying to help me in Freenode's #regex came up with something similar via another validator)? Anyways, thanks again; who knows what goes on with that app.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the locations of `objectID` and `objectType`, then select the data relative to those positions.

```
require(stringr)
objectID_loc <- str_locate(x, "objectID")
objectType_loc <- str_locate(x, "objectType")
objectID <- substr(x, objectID_loc[, "end"] + 2, objectType_loc[, "start"] - 3)
```

That gives you:

```
> objectID
[1] "1900"
```

Comment: Thank you. I selected the first correct response but this works too. I upvoted you.

Comment: Technically, I beat him by a few seconds. Alas! ;D glad you found something that works

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if you answered first, my mistake!